# Issue while redirecting bad row - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm Importing data from a flat file source (text comma delimited) into a table, but the data contains comma in certain fields causing the package to fail. I have added a file destination to log the bad rows to revisit later, but the bad rows don't get logged and the only part of the data get loaded in the table. I'm attaching below the image of the package and the incomplete execution screen. It looks like a simple thing to accomplish but I just can't figure out what causing the problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

There is no error message in Progress actually. It looks like a successful run log. But it's not. The load is incomplete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the Flat File Destination. Drag a new Flat File Destination task into the Data Flow field, but don't configure it yet. Right click on your Flat File Source and go to "Show Advanced Editor". On the "Input and Output Properties" tab, make sure you have output configured under "Flat File Source Error Output". They were probably created automatically by BIDS/VS. Once you have error output columns, click "OK" to close the window.
Next, drag the red error output arrow from the source to the destination. This should bring up the "Configure Error Output" window. Make sure all the rows under "Error" and "Truncation" are set to "Redirect Row" and click "OK"
Finally, open up the Flat File Destination, and create a new connection manager. Point the connection manager to your error output file, and then set your column and row delimiters. You may also want to set a Text Delimiter. 
Once you have all those pieces, your error rows should be redirected to your error output file. If not, please post back your error message(s) and sample data.

Comment: It was already set as you said, Just in case , I started over and do step by step as you described and still have the same issue. I'm wondering if the inputs and outputs tab of the connection manager for the source should look like this (see screen attached). The data source contains 10 fields they looked to be concatenated in one in the flat file output columns.

Comment: The 10 fields from the source will be concatenated into a single column for the error output. I'm not sure which screenshot you're referring to (I can only see two screen shots up in your original question post). Can you post the actual error you get when trying to run the package?

Comment: In the second picture in my initial post, there is a  blue link saying "Package execution completed. Click here to switch to design mode, or select the stop debugging from the debug menu". This implies that the package has completed and not doing any further work while the 3,7M records loaded are not the entire file and there is no green check marks on each task which usually indicates a successful completion. As for the output error, I'm going to post another screenshot below with the progress log as I can't post it in the comment section.

Comment: I'm missing about 2k records.

Comment: Do you know if the records are all at the end of the file, or are they interspersed?

Answer (score -1):

In the Flat File Connection Manager, on the first page, you can pick a Text Qualifier, which is typically double quotes. Most programs that read CSV files know how to interpret strings encased in double quotes.

So now a single column value of

```
123 My Street, Any Town, USA
```

become:

```
"123 My Street, Any Town, USA"
```

Pretty standard stuff for CSV files